# Can dynamic VHD files shrink or do they just grow?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vhd

You can create dynamic VHD files that will gradually grow towards a maximum size. Do they shrink as well? And if they don't, can you make it shrink back down to whatever size it actually needs to be at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they do not shrink by themselves, but you can shrink them manually.

Remember to run the [pre-compactor](http://sharevm.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/what-does-the-vhd-pre-compactor-do/) tool before shrinking it.

In Hyper-V you shrink it from the disk settings dialog. If you're not running a virtualization suite I'm not sure how you are suppose to do it though - but there's a tool called [VHD Resizer](http://vmtoolkit.com/files/folders/converters/entry87.aspx) that might help.

Comment: How would you shrink it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth looking at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/51336/how-to-shrink-the-size-of-a-virtual-machine-hard-disk) similar question with 5 or six answers. I suspect you can ignore the one about 'putting it in the dryer'.